# The many world interpretation and immortality

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-interpretations, measurement-problem, schroedingers-cat

This question might not be appropriate as it is philosophical on a similar level as the Schrödinger's cat thought experiment. In any case it might be interesting to think about it nonetheless.

The reason why I put it here, is to get the thoughts of others on it, as I don't really know what to make of it.

Ok. The main assumption (1) is, that there is no live after death. That is, when an observer is dead, thats it. There is no path for her afterwards.

Now consider the many world interpretation (2) of quantum mechanics, in the way that all possible alternate histories and futures are real, each representing an actual universe.

I would argue that under these assumptions and solely from an observers subjective perspective, the observer is actually immortal then. In contrast, the worlds behave normal for everybody else.

To see that lets assume that an observer plays Russian roulette with a single bullet in a revolver with a revolving cylinder that has six chambers. The observer has a 1/6th chance for the bullet to be fired. So from an outside observer, in one out of six shots she will be dead, statistically speaking.

However from the perspective of the observer, who uses the gun, she can never travel the future path, where the bullet kills her, under the death assumption (1). So she can never find herself in a universe, where the bullet was fired. But according to (2), she will find (a copy of herself) in a universe, where the bullet was not fired.

Now I would argue, that the playing observer herself, never experience the bullet to be fired. Because this might be a future path for the external observer, but not a future path for herself. She will always find herself on a path, where she actually exists.

We can make this even worse, by loading six bullets into the chamber. Still there is a slight chance for her to survive, as there might be a misfire. From the outside we will see her dying almost every time, but subjectively the only path/universe she could find herself in, is the one with the misfire.

We could make this game arbitrarily silly by making her survival chance ridiculously small, however according to the rules of QM there will always be chance to survive. It doesn't matter how small the chance is. Altogether this should mean that subjectively, no one can die under assumption (1) and (2), or can we? At the same time, this is completely unobservable from the outside.

Ok. I think you get the idea. What do you think? If this is inappropriate for physics.stackexchange, suggest another board then.

Comment: Well first this doesn't say anything about immortality, it just means that you don't die from getting shot. Second, there is nothing new here... After one firing of the gun we have five scenarios of death and one where the observer lives. But in that "world" you can easily say that you got lucky. Of course the alive observer only experiences the bullet not being fired. I'm confused as to how this is anything other than a game of chance. 5 observers will definitely experience a bullet to the head, and one will not.

Comment: No afterlife + many world's interpretation does not necessarily lead to this conclusion at all.  It seems more likely to me that even if many world's is true, we are essentially confined to one of the streams, and there's no real reason to assume it's the one where you live.  As far as physics is concerned, there doesn't really seem to be a reason for a conciousness to have to keep living.  By the "observer" logic, all our measurement devices should also still be "alive" in one of the many world where they somehow live.  There's no physical basis for it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not really a question about physics.

Comment: @Aaron: 1.) The Russian Roulette is of course just an example. The same reasoning however applies to any situation where an observer might die.  2.) What do you mean with "new here". No one claims anything new. Its a subjectified version of Schrödingers cat, from the perspective of the cat, basically.

Comment: @JMac: "It seems more likely to me that even if many world's is true, we are essentially confined to one of the streams, and there's no real reason to assume it's the one where you live." Which rule is it? The many world interpretation says, that every path is real in some world.

Comment: Beside, one could argue that the many world theory is also not about physics then, because we can never measure it.

Comment: I somehow agree with you, but there is another issue, what is there are two survival possibilities, one in which it doesnt fire and one in which it fires, and maims you but it does not kill you. You will experience both streams, so basically you will experience multiple futures. Well, not you, but different versions of you. At this point we should redefine what "you" means.

Comment: @Wolphram jonny: Yes, one of the major problems with the many world interpretation is, that technically there are often uncountable infinite many possibilities (if spacetime is continuous) for any event, in any moment in time. Most of them with a ridiculously small probability. But in that interpretation, they all happen for real in some fork of the universe. ... So actually playing Russian roulette might cripple you to  a certain point. But not to the point where you are not an observer anymore. This is crazy of course.

Comment: I think this means that the many world interpretation does not solve the observer problem.

Comment: I think it does, the evolution is unitary, you just have to give up on having a single stream of consciousness

Comment: @MarkNeuhaus Every possible path would be real in some world; but that doesn't automatically mean you must follow the path in which you avoid death.   It seems more reasonable to assume you're not some privileged observer who would somehow always choose the surviving path.

Comment: You may enjoy this page, and its links. https://rationalwiki.org/wiki/Quantum_suicide

Comment: Thats really interesting indeed. And its basically also a good answer to the problem of Quantum_suicide/immortality

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a question about quantum mechanics. It uses classical information and classical probability. What makes quantum mechanics different is that it takes place in a complex Hilbert space, with unitary time evolution. The argument made in the question doesn't use any of these features that are specific to quantum mechanics. It simply states, correctly, that in a system that evolves stochastically, it may be possible to reach outcomes that are arbitrarily surprising because they have arbitrarily low probability.

Comment: I think in the many world interpretation everything is a quantum system. Thats why I used the gun, not a, say, particle decay trigger, or something. If you rotate the bullet chamber, then, among an uncountable number of other things, the particles, the chamber is made of, fork into Universes with the six possible chamber positions at the end.